# How to reference and pull all cells that have a blank in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

I input data into one sheet (Emptys) and am trying to grab a cell from another sheet (report) in the same row that has a blank in a certain column.

Sample Report:
[image]

I am trying to pull the value from column A if the cell in the same row of column M is empty and reference that to a different sheet.

I am also trying to skip any rows that have a value in them and only pull the data from the rows that have a blank in column M.

All I have gotten to work is this basic formula:

```
=IF( Report!M2= "",Report!A2, "" )
```

I still have to sort out empties manually this way.

```vb
Dim myrange
Dim id
 
myrange = Sheets("Report").Range("M2:M")
id = Sheets("Empty_Slots").Range("A2:A")
 
For Each cell In myrange
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        id = Sheets("Report").Range("A2:A")
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried?

Comment: I added what I have tried so far.

Comment: `"M2:M"` is not an appropriate reference.  One must supply the end row of the range.

Answer (score 0):

You may access row numbers of those blank cells and use them in worksheet 2:

[image]

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim wk1 As Worksheet
Dim wk2 As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim rng As Range


Set wk1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wk2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

With wk1
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last non blank cell in column a
    For Each rng In .Range("M2:M" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) 'array of blank cells in column M
        wk2.Range("A" & rng.Row).Interior.Color = vbYellow 'do something with column A from worksheet2 based on row numbers from column M in worksheet 1
    Next rng
End With

Set wk1 = Nothing
Set wk2 = Nothing


End Sub
```

The code loops trough each blank cell in column M from Sheet1 and pulls the row number. Then in worksheet 2 it uses that row number in column A.

After executing code, I've colored cells in sheet2 but based on sheet1

[image]